# how i pass multiple variables from view to controller in codeigniter inside form_open

Tags: codeigniter

my view page

i have variables $month,$year,$id.in my viewpage.i want to pass this to controller function using echo form_open for updation

```
  echo form_open('money_c/updatemanualdata/'.$id,$month,$year);?>
```

how will call this in my controller money_c

`function updatemanualdata('')..?>`here what will i put please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form action will be

```
echo form_open('money_c/updatemanualdata/'.$id.'/'.$month.'/'.$year);
```

You can catch that in your controller using url segment like this.
be sure to load the url helper `$this->load->helper('url')`

```
function updatemanualdata($id, $month, $year){}
```